# Queries with NOLOCK using Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

I'd like to know how can I tell Sequelize to make SELECT queries with NOLOCK.

I'm using Sequelize with tedious to connect on SQL Server 2008.

I found nothing on the docs.

Comment: Can you show us the SQL query you have already please?

Comment: I'm talking about the queries that the Models do, for example:

User.find({ where: { name = "Igor" } }).then

The query is something like this:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE NAME = 'Igor';

Comment: Do you really want nolock? Are you ok with mostly correct information most of the time? nolock is far more than just dirty reads. You might read about many of the other details here http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I'm not sure what I really want, but for now, I just need to know if it is possible to tell Sequelize to make Model queries with NOLOCK.

I'm reading the article, Sean.

Comment: If you aren't certain then trust me, you don't want NOLOCK. It creates some random errors that are impossible to reproduce due to things like page movement (which you can read about in the link above).

Comment: there are other ways of doing NO LOCK such as setting the transaction isolation level of the connection to READ UNCOMMITTED.  I'm guessing you are perhaps running large reports or data mining?

Comment: mssqlserver have this no lock nightmare. nice question. nice answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Sequelize v4.37.0, [`TableHint` is now supported.](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#table-hint)

Example:

```js
Project.findAll({
    tableHint: TableHints.NOLOCK // only can specify one
});
```